# How to access the methods from WADL file in Java?

Tags: java, methods, wadl

I have a REST service for which I have a WADL file. I want to refer this file and access the methods from it.  The content of the WADL file is as below:

```xml
<resource path="/loadPerson">
    <method id="loadPerson" name="GET">
        <request>
            <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="personId" style="query" type="xs:int"/>
        </request>
        <response>
            <ns2:representation xmlns:ns2="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns="" element="person" mediaType="application/xml"/>
            <ns2:representation xmlns:ns2="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns="" element="person" mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
    </method>
</resource>
```

Actually I am not getting how to approach towards it, as I never played with WADL files before. What should I be doing?

Comment: This is not a real question, right? You'd google it.

Comment: @Alexander: I did google a lot, but not find the exact solution what I am expecting. Basically I am getting that how do I handle request and response parameter from this WADL file. Correct me if I am wrong that as per my understanding in above posted part of code of WADL file "loadPerson" is a method and personID is a input parameter. But how to access it in java? what things I needed to do that?

Comment: I think that my comment still stands.

Comment: What you want to tell I am not getting. Can you please advice me how to call this method from my project using WADL? Please I need it urgently and I got a stuck here. I am new to web projects in Java.

Comment: This file is not a "method," it tells you where you can find other methods as resources. First, get acquainted with WADLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<resource>` identifies a URL (with respect to a base URL specified as a `base` attribute on an outer `<resources>` element that you don't show) that you would interact with in a RESTful manner. The `<method>` has a `name` attribute of GET, which means that to use that particular operation, you do a GET on the resource URL. The inner `<request>` has a `<param>` so we know to add a query parameter to the GET URL; in this case, it'll be `personId=123` (or some other integer). The `<response>` tells us that we can get back the answer as either XML or JSON; we should use HTTP content negotiation to say which.

There's a minor bug in the WADL in that it is specifying the `<resource>` URL with a leading `/`; that will quite possibly cause problems with tooling as it tries to assemble a correct URL, but we can still say what the URL will be (from knowing how RESTful webapps tend to be implemented).

Assuming that the outer `<resources>` says that the base URL is `http://example.org/foobar` (and there's no intermediate `<resource>` elements; WADL allows that) then the WADL is saying that if you do a GET on `http://example.org/foobar/loadPerson?personId=123` with your HTTP client configured to prefer XML, you'll get a `<person>` element back as the body of the HTTP response (or an error, e.g., if there's no match for such a `personId` or if you're not authorized to find out).

Comment: I run my project and also tried to access the method from URL as http://localhost:8080/proj-name/resource-path/loadPerson?personId=123 but I got the error on the browser as HTTP 401 - Unauthorized. (In this case resource-path=/loadPerson). Is this correct way to call? I think it is correct bcoz it is giving error of Unauthorization.

Comment: Another method I tried to access from the same WADL file by entering URL like: http://localhost:8080/openempi-admin/openempi-ws-rest/person-query-resource/findRaceByCode/?method=findRaceByCode()&raceCode=100. But I got same error of Authentication.  :(